# Can't switch PreferenceFragment from ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-appcompat, preferencefragment

Hi i have an activity that extends `ActionBarActivity`. This one, has a `ViewPager` using `PagerSlidingTabStrip` library. I'm using AppCompat v21 so i need extends ActionBarActivity to use the toolbar. By the way.. I have two PreferenceFragment that i need put in this viewpager.

```
    import com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip;
import com.zst.app.multiwindowsidebar.preference.*;
import com.zst.app.multiwindowsidebar.sidebar.SidebarService;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.transition.Explode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
//import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {
    public static final int MENU_TOGGLE = 1;

    public enum PAGES {
        MAIN(0),
        APPEARENCE(1);

        final int position;
        PAGES(int pos) {
            position = pos;
        }
    };

    MyPagerAdapter mPageAdapter;

    // Add
    Toolbar toolbar;
    public static PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;
    public ViewPager pager;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
        getWindow().setEnterTransition( new Explode() );
        getWindow().setExitTransition( new Explode() );
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        mPageAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()); 

        pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip)findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        pager.setAdapter(mPageAdapter);
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);

        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

        mPageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        pager.invalidate();
    }

    // My adapter
    public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private final String[] TITLES = { "Home", "Interfaccia" };

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return TITLES[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return TITLES.length;
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;

        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new MainPrefFragment();
            case 1:
                return new AppearencePrefFragment();

            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_TOGGLE, 0, R.string.pref_toggle_service_title)
            .setIcon(SidebarService.isRunning ?
                    R.drawable.ic_menu_toggle_off : R.drawable.ic_menu_toggle_on)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case MENU_TOGGLE:
            if (SidebarService.isRunning) {
                SidebarService.stopSidebar(this);
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_toggle_on);
            } else {
                startService(new Intent(this, SidebarService.class));
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_toggle_off);
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

But i get errors like: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from AppearencePrefFragment to Fragment` ... How can i do?

ps: i tried to import the support-v13 but seems collide with v7

Comment: Could you show your LogCat output

Comment: I have no logcat because the error is over `return new MainPrefFragment();` and `return new AppearencePrefFragment();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `PreferenceFragment` with `getFragmentManager` even if you're using `ActionBarActivity` (on APIs above 11 of course).

> But i get errors like: Type mismatch: cannot convert from AppearencePrefFragment to Fragment ...

The problem is the `FragmentPagerAdapter` only takes either support or native implementation of fragment manager. This means you can't combine native and support fragments inside the pager.

**Option 1:** Use native (ahem.. I mean support-v13) `FragmentPagerAdapter` and convert all your fragments to native.

The word is though there are some bugs in native fragment implementations varying with API, so I wouldn't choose this option.

**Option 2:** Use support (support-v4) `FragmentPagerAdapter` and a support version of `PreferenceFragment`.

Add the following dependency in your *module* `build.gradle` file

```
compile('com.android.support:support-v4-preferencefragment:1.+@aar') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Add it's repository to your *project* `build.gradle` file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // this is the one
            url "https://raw.github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment/master/maven-repository/"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Finally have your preference fragment extend `android.support.v4.preference.PreferenceFragment` instead of `android.preference.PreferenceFragment`. Please note that despite it's name this is not an official backport, but I've been using it quite successfully for some time.

Comment: But if i am including support-v7, why have i to use support-v4?

Comment: `ActionBarActivity` from `appcompat-v7` extends `FragmentActivity` from `support-v4`, both using support fragments from `support-v4`. You're using `support-v4` and don't even know it ;)

Comment: only one problem, i use eclipse and not android studio :(

Comment: In that case clone [this GitHub project](https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment) and import it to your Eclipse project as a library. Then make your application depend on this library.

Comment: Or Option 2: switch to AS :D

Comment: Ok wait ahahah i'm going crazy! Downloaded and imported the library in eclipse, then, build path - Configure Build Path -  Android. Added the dependencies right?

Comment: Nonono, Properties for <app> -> Android -> Library -> Add... If the library is not in the list, go to the same section in the preference fragment library properties and tick "Is Library".